# Jquery - onclick not triggered for dynamic created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue, Jquery onclick not triggered for dynamic created elements. I am using Jquery 1.9 and tried the example with "ON" and "LIVE". But still its not working. can some 1 help me?.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function (e) {..});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cindrella_agi/6hjp9/2)

Comment: Are you writting the JQuery code that associates the event to the element before the elements are added to the document?

Comment: Can we stop answering this question and let them search for it on stack overflow. This question has probably been answered at least 50 times

Comment: Thanks all.. i used DELEGATE and it worked fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the event handler to

```
$(document).on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", function (e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have create and append elements using javascript, you have to set new event handler for that. event handlers set before adding the elements will not work for those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your function into document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function (e) {..});
})
```

I think it will help you to solve your issue.

Demo: [fidder](http://jsfiddle.net/6hjp9/12/)